# Error: free() double free detected in tcache 2

Tags: c++, struct, compiler-errors, ifstream

These lines of code are giving me the error: free() double free detected in tcache 2 when I attempt to run the program. If i remove the final line, there is no error.  append_new is a method that searches the array within item_vec and adds "initialString" to the end of the array.  The method append_new has been tested in other programs. Could someone please explain the reason for this error and how to fix?

```
class item_vec {
    // Create private set of variables 
private:
    int strSize;
    int strCapacity;
    string* arr;

// Define functions in public
public:

    item_vec()
        : strSize(0), strCapacity(10)
    {
        arr = new string[strCapacity];
    }

    item_vec(int n, string s)
        : strSize(n), strCapacity(2 * n + 1)  // initializer list
    {
        // Check for out of bounds error
        if (n < 0) {
            cmpt::error("str_vec(int n, string s): n must be 0 or greater");
        }
        // make array and populate with string s
        arr = new string[strCapacity];
        for (int i = 0; i < strSize; i++) {
            arr[i] = s;
        }
    }

    int size() const {
        return strSize;
    }

    void append_new(string s) {
        // Variable to track if string is already present
        bool hasString = false;
        // Iterate through and update if string found
        for (int i = 0; i < strSize; i++) {
            if (arr[i] == s) {
                hasString = true;
            }
        }
        // If string isnt found append to end
        if (hasString == false) {

            // Make new copy array and replace old if no space
            if (strSize >= strCapacity) {
                strCapacity *= 2;
                string* new_arr = new string[strCapacity];

                for (int i = 0; i < strSize; i++) {
                    new_arr[i] = arr[i];
                }
                delete[] arr;
                arr = new_arr;
                delete[] new_arr;
            }
            // Update array
            arr[strSize] = s;
            strSize++;
        }
    }

    // Make destructor
    ~item_vec() {
        delete[] arr;
    }
};
```

Comment: Bug's here: `delete[] new_arr;` You don't want to delete the new array. You just assigned it to `arr`, so what's `arr` gonna point at?

Comment: wow, thank you that was an easy mistake.  I have a separate program, where this type of error never appeared whilst the function was defined the exact same way.

Comment: That's [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) for you. Sometimes the program keeps going and looks like everything is OK. [Then this happens](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=73wMnU7xbwE). You can bet that demonstration worked many times before Bill Gates was willing to get up on stage in front of cameras.

Comment: @tg8 *The method append_new has been tested in other programs* -- Even with the fix others have suggested, your class is still very easily broken: `int main() { item_vec v1; item_vec v2 = v1; }`.  You now have a double-delete error after `main` returns.  Read up on the [rule of 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).  Until you make those changes, using `item_vec` in any program is not safe, as shown by that simple 2-line program having issues.

Answer (score 0):

In `append_new` after the old array has been copied into the new array we find

```
            delete[] arr; // free the old array. Good. No leak
            arr = new_arr; // point at the new array
            delete[] new_arr; // Whoooaaa! arr's pointing at that!
```

The program will be broken as soon as the now-`delete`ed array at `arr` is used. The program may may stagger on, mortally wounded, for a while after that, and it looks like it makes it to the next `delete[] arr;` where the program notices the array's already been `delete`ed and crashes to make sure you also know about the mistake, but it's no longer going to function correctly and the error could [manifest in any manner of strange and unexpected ways](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) at any time.

Solution: Remove

```
            delete[] new_arr;
```